# I'm trying to list startup programs in C by using registry

Tags: c, windows

I'm beginner in C and I want to make a program that lists all the startup programs in windows..

I figured out I can do this by opening the registers
so I opened the registers. 
    `ret = RegOpenKeyEx (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE , TEXT ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);`

and read
`ret = RegQueryValueEx (hKey, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), 0, &d_type, (LPBYTE)d_buffer, &d_byte );`

my question is how can I get the strings(program names) from those registries?
I've been struggling due to the error when I tried to make an char arr[]; and move the values into it.

so maybe I'm doing something wrong..  should I use pointer or something?

could anyone give me some clues for this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the flow goes like this :
1) open the registry key (registers are completly different things)
2) ask how many registry values the key has
3) iterate over them and get their data (which is what you are looking for)

this code snippet get the `keyHandle`, enumerate the values, and get theit data into a buffer

```
DWORD numberOfValues;
LONG result = RegQueryInfoKey(
    keyHandle,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &numberOfValues,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL);

wchar_t valueName [300];
DWORD bufferSize;

for (DWORD i = 0; i<numberOfValues; i++){
    bufferSize = 300;
    LONG result = RegEnumValue(
        keyHandle,
        i,
        valueName,
        &bufferSize,
        0,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &bufferSize);
    if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS){
        valueName[bufferSize] = 0;
        //do something with valueName, this is the name of the program

    }
}
```

note: this program assume you define your program as Unicode program. (you should, since you can't really espect that all program names will be named in pure english)
note2 : I do realize you learn C, which is a woderfull language to start with, but this task was much easier using C++ or C#. keep that in mind for future tasks.

Comment: okay, to be honest I hadn't considered to make it unicode, so, it's good to know. and I'll keep that in mind, actually was thinking to learn c++. :)  anyways thanks David! it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
RegQueryValueEx (hKey, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), 0, &d_type, (LPBYTE)d_buffer, &d_byte );
```

RegQueryValueEx only works if you know the name of the value in advance.

```
RegQueryValueEx (hKey, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), "SmartAudio", &d_type, (LPBYTE)d_buffer, &d_byte );
```

If there is value with the name Smart Audio then it will print Data. But if you don't know name of value then you may use

```
int main()
{
  system("C:\\Windows\\system32\\reg.exe QUERY HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
}
```

It will give you output like this - [image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, since you're just producing external output and not actually getting the names in code

Comment: Yeah, That's a simple way to get the output! Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: @YelahJung I'm glad :) general rule upvote or accept answer !